# Android:change the the TEXT color of Selected list Item in Java

Tags: java, android

I am working on a dynamic Android application in Java where a list view gets values from database.

What I am looking for is how to change the TEXT color of Selected list Item in that list, and the color of that text should remain changed to indicate that this item has been selected, no matter if the activity has been changed. Whenever we come back to that activity to make another selection, that color changing item should be there still with the changed Text color.

Comment: Have you try something ??

Comment: Which is your question? How to change the text color when selecting an item or how to keep the selection returning to the Activity? Or both??

Comment: Changing the color is trivial (as long as you read up on it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(int)). Saving the state can be done in a million different ways: write to DB, to SharedPreferences, to a Sarver...

Comment: Have to taken custom layout for listview row or inbuilt android textview layout

Comment: i just want to change the text color of selected item so i get back to that activity i could simply see that these items are already seen.like we see color of visited hyper link gets changed to indicate that it has been visited.
yes i tried different codes i found on Google but did not get my point in them,please do let me know how can i solve this code mystery, i am new in android development.

Comment: @user543
i am using custom text views for rows in list view

Answer (score 0):

When you select an item, you will need to save that information in a static data structure. If you want the selection to be persistent (even if the app is closed), then you will need to store the selection indicator in your database. When you read your database to extra the data, use the "selection indicator" in your adapter to decide what color to use.

Simply changing the textColor of your textField will not persist when you return to that activity.